# how to compare the value in the same table in a different column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comparison

so i have a verification table consists of key_id, key_verification, confirm_key, and key_status

this is the sql process for client_verifycodez.php where i want to compare the value of key_verification and confirm_key if they are the same

the update sql is needed so that when client enter the key fro a form, it will enter into db as confirm_key. so by that i want to compare the value of confirm_key with the already existing key_verification

```
    $sql1 = "UPDATE verification SET confirm_key = '".$confirm_key."' WHERE key_id ='".$id."'";
    mysql_query($sql1);

    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM verification WHERE key_verification = confirm_key");
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
    $check = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if($check==true)
    {
    echo "<center>";
    echo "Your key is invalid!";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href=client_verifycodez.php>Back </a>";
    echo "</center>";
    }
    else
    {
    header("Location: home.php");
    }
```

so what i need is how do i compare so that when key_verification and confirm_key is equals, it will go to home.php or else alert. i think i have the problem with the sql.

can anyone perhaps help me? thank you

Comment: This looks strange. If your query is true, what means that the keys match, it says your key is invalid. Was that intentional?

Comment: @YUNOWORK sorry it's not query but check

Comment: yes, ok, but this doesnt change the sense ... if you query contains something, $check becomes true because a filled variable is almost always true. And if its true, you output that the code is invalid, even if its valid ... i dont get it. Maybe im too tired, but for me, this condition looks wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do like this, use sub-query,

```
"SELECT * FROM verification WHERE key_id =". $id ." AND key_verification
 = (SELECT confirm_key FROM verification WHERE key_id =". $id .")"
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_num_rows() function will return the number of existing rows count

please use mysqli extension always

```
<?php

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM verification WHERE key_verification = confirm_key");

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());

//get the number of result rows
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

//get the details
$check = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if($query)
{
    if($num_rows>0)
    {
    echo "<center>";
    echo "Your key is invalid!";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href=client_verifycodez.php>Back </a>";
    echo "</center>";
    }
    else
    {
    header("Location: home.php");
    }
}
```